# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x16fc5da60) in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, uipickerview, viewdidload

In my ViewController I have 15 PickerView and 15 text field. In the text field editing did begin function I am creating proper picker view. In my viewDidLoad method first of all I am giving their delegate and data sources in there with following code.

```
self.firstPicker = UIPickerView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
self.firstPicker.delegate = self
self.firstPicker.dataSource = self


//When text field editing did begin function called following is executing.
    func pickUpFirstPicker(_ textField : UITextField) {

self.kodPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
textField.inputView = self.kodPicker

// ToolBar
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = .default
toolBar.isTranslucent = true
toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
toolBar.sizeToFit()

// Adding Button ToolBar
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(FiltreVC.pickerDoneClick))
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "CANCEL", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(FiltreVC.pickerCancelClick))
toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }


@objc func pickerDoneClick() {
    // 400 lines of if else statement

if (Services.list[sampleIndex].pageName == "XYZ" ||
    Services.list[sampleIndex].pageName == "ABC") {
                if (selected == 1) {
                //
                    firstView.isHidden = true
                    secondView.isHidden = true
                    thirdView.isHidden  = false
                } else if (selected == 2) {
                    firstView.isHidden = false
                    secondView.isHidden = false
                    thirdView.isHidden = true
                    firstPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
                    pickerDoneClick()
                }
            }

}
```

After giving delegate and data sources of picker view's I am calling a function (still in my viewDidLoad) that is about 400 line of if-else statement. According to proper if statement it select a picker with selectRow function then it is calling the function that I mentioned above which is pickerDoneClick. It is working well if I use that pickerDoneClick function in my picker bar button done click. However, if I use it in my viewDidLoad it is giving me error Thread 1: **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x16fc5da60)**. Also it is **working fine in simulator** there is no problem but **in the real devices it is giving me an error**. What could be the reason and how can I solve it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it in my viewDidLoad I am calling pickerDoneClick() function. I put exception breakpoint and it crashed there.

Comment: Where was the crash exactly? Here, please delete all code that's not interesting: creation of the button items, setting styles, ... Do the same in your running code: Delete everything that's not needed, until you're left with just a few lines in which the crash still appears.

Comment: It is not even entering pickerDoneClick() it is crashing when debug line is on the function.